# Trouble with Google Vision API key

Tags: .net, json, google-vision

I am trying to use Google Vision API in my WinForms (.NET) project. I have signed up in Google Cloud Platform and enabled Vision API. Having followed Google Cloud standard steps in authorization process I have created and downloaded service key in JSON format. As far as it is concerned, GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS also have been set to be pointing to key file (JSON file I have mentioned before). All settings are looking good in Google Cloud Platform, in terms of API.

I am wondering why I am getting exception

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated,Detail="Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occured in metadata credentials plugin.")'

Here is the code of method where exception is thrown:

```
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
        var response = client.DetectText(image); // <- here exception is thrown
```

P.S. I have made a significant research on this topic. I know it seems something is wrong with authentication, can't figure out what exactly is wrong though.

P.S.S Should you have any references or tutorials, don't hesitate to provide me with them.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your sample should work as long as the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set accordingly.

To debug, you may want to add a line like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Using credentials from {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")}.");
```